# Unable to create dialog box with gui.fileOpenDlg()

Tags: python, dialog, psychopy

Psychopy version: v2022.2.5

I am trying to use `gui.fileOpenDlg()` to create a dialog box that allows me to select the condition file (.xslx) before starting my experiment. But somehow it doesn't work for me.

- My .py file is in folder "pilotZone" and my target .xlsx files are all in pilotZone/participant_stimulus_sheet folder.
- All the .xlsx files are named "participant_stim1.xlsx, participant_stim2.xlsx...etc."

## **source code of** `gui.fileOpenDlg()`

(from [https://psychopy.org/_modules/psychopy/gui/qtgui.html#fileOpenDlg](https://stackoverflow.com) )

```
def fileOpenDlg(tryFilePath="",
                tryFileName="",
                prompt=_translate("Select file to open"),
                allowed=None):
    """A simple dialogue allowing read access to the file system.

    :parameters:

        tryFilePath: string
            default file path on which to open the dialog

        tryFileName: string
            default file name, as suggested file

        prompt: string (default "Select file to open")
            can be set to custom prompts

        allowed: string (available since v1.62.01)
            a string to specify file filters.
            e.g. "Text files (\\*.txt) ;; Image files (\\*.bmp \\*.gif)"
            See https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html
            #getOpenFileNames
            for further details

    If tryFilePath or tryFileName are empty or invalid then
    current path and empty names are used to start search.

    If user cancels, then None is returned.
    """
    ensureQtApp()

    if allowed is None:
        allowed = ("All files (*.*);;"
                   "PsychoPy Data (*.psydat);;"
                   "txt (*.txt *.dlm *.csv);;"
                   "pickled files (*.pickle *.pkl);;"
                   "shelved files (*.shelf)")
    fdir = os.path.join(tryFilePath, tryFileName)
    filesToOpen = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(parent=None,
                                                         caption=prompt,
                                                         directory=fdir,
                                                         filter=allowed)
    if type(filesToOpen) == tuple:  # some versions(?) of PyQt return (files, filter)
        filesToOpen = filesToOpen[0]

    filesToOpen = [str(fpath) for fpath in filesToOpen
                   if os.path.exists(fpath)]
    if len(filesToOpen) == 0:
        return None
    return filesToOpen
```

## **My current code:**

```
# --- Import packages ---
from psychopy import locale_setup
from psychopy import prefs
from psychopy import sound, gui, visual, core, data, event, logging, clock, colors, layout
from psychopy.constants import (NOT_STARTED, STARTED, PLAYING, PAUSED,
                                STOPPED, FINISHED, PRESSED, RELEASED, FOREVER)

import numpy as np  # whole numpy lib is available, prepend 'np.'
from numpy import (sin, cos, tan, log, log10, pi, average,
                   sqrt, std, deg2rad, rad2deg, linspace, asarray)
from numpy.random import random, randint, normal, shuffle, choice as randchoice
import os  # handy system and path functions
import sys  # to get file system encoding

from psychopy.hardware import keyboard



# Ensure that relative paths start from the same directory as this script
_thisDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(_thisDir)
# Store info about the experiment session
psychopyVersion = '2022.2.5'
expName = 'TLBX_Alpha0510core'  # from the Builder filename that created this script
expInfo = {
    'participant': f"{randint(0, 999999):06.0f}",
    'session': '001',
}

#--- select stimulus .xlsx file--- #
dlg = gui.fileOpenDlg(tryFilePath="pilotZone/participant_stimulus_sheet",tryFileName= ,prompt'Select file to open'= ,allowed=None)
```

## **Error message:**

```
## Running: /Users/jamesabcd/Desktop/TLBX_experiment/pilotZone/TLBX_Alpha0510core.py ##
  File "/Users/jamesabcd/Desktop/TLBX_experiment/pilotZone/TLBX_Alpha0510core.py", line 44
    dlg = gui.fileOpenDlg(tryFilePath="pilotZone/participant_stimulus_sheet",tryFileName= ,prompt'Select file to open'= ,allowed=None)
                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
################# Experiment ended with exit code 1 [pid:2961] #################
```

I suspect I misused this function but have no idea how to fix it. :/